# Is there a limit to the number of <Input> tag in a <Form> tag for HTML/Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, html, apache, post, input

Ok, this is weird. I have created a simple addressbook using php with mysql back end. 
So I added up to 138 rows of addresses, it's all fine. BTW I display my addresses in input texts so that any user can edit it anytime. So when I press a submit button, it perform http post on all 138 line entries and updates them. Everything is fine....

However, one fine day when I tried to update a 139th row input, it drops the last input input and give an ERROR! It gives a php run time error: "Notice: Undefined index: lastN in C:\wamp\www\Dawah\go.php on line 24".

btw the LastN variable is obtained using $_post['lastN'].

As if there is a limit to the number of html input tags that can be posted in a single form!

I am very much intrigued.

Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: it'd be `$_POST['lastN']`. PHP variable names and array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: Post your code, but it probably is exactly what @MarcB is saying.

Comment: sorry it is $_POST['lastN'], my typo... it's still not working though. THanks for the fast replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's an suhosin setting `suhosin.request.max_vars` but that's only for suhosin, not regular php.

since php 5.3.9 theres `max_input_vars`, which seems to fit the behavior
http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

apache has settings to limit request size, but they're specified in bytes, not number of variables, as far as I know. I'd imagine apache would just stop and issue abad request instead of truncating the data like you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks! but where is the max_input_vars parameter sotred in? I can't find it anywhere in PHP.ini file.

Comment: use phpinfo() to find the correct php.ini file to edit, and to check if the setting applies to your version.